# Fetch in Javascript "Unexpected end of input"

Tags: javascript, html, json, xml, fetch

**Solved!
I removed the header reqHeader.append("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
and changed mode from no-cors to cors.**

I'm trying to understand how to retrieve json from the web using both XMLHttpRequest and Fetch in JS.
So I simply created an index.html, a fetch.js and xmlhttprequest.js

I'm not having problems with xmlhttprequest.js, it works fine, meanwhile fetch.js gives me an Unexpected end of input error.

Any idea?

index.html ->

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <script src="fetch.js"></script>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="content"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

fetch.js ->

```
let reqHeader = new Headers();
reqHeader.append('Content-Type', 'text/json');
reqHeader.append("accept", "application/json");
reqHeader.append("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

let initObject = {
    method: 'GET',
    mode: 'no-cors',
    headers: reqHeader
};

let myRequest = new Request('https://www.dati.lombardia.it/resource/nmru-kdry.json', initObject);

fetch(myRequest)
.then(response => {
    console.log("Ricevo: ", response.status);
    console.log("Da: ", response.url);
    return response.json();
})
.then(data => document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = data[0].denominazione)
.catch(err => console.log("An Error: ", err))
```

xmlhttprequest.js ->

```
function load(data) {
    document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = data[0].denominazione + '<br>';
}

function success() {
    let data = JSON.parse(this.response);

    console.log('Ricevo: ', this.status);
    console.log('Da: ', this.responseURL);
    load(data);
};

function error(err) {
    console.log('An Error: ', err);
};

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onload = success;
xhr.onerror = error;

xhr.open('GET', 'https://www.dati.lombardia.it/resource/nmru-kdry.json');
xhr.send();
```

Comment: The fetch works if you remove the `mode` from the `initObject` and `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` from `reqHeaders`. I don't know the details as to why